# Please tell me how to answer the board using ASP.NEC MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypEbm.jpg)

I want to use ASP.NET MVC to create such a bulletin board.
But I just do not know because I have just learned.
If you have any relevant code or information to help me, can you tell me?
Below is my code for reference.
My controller, view, model code.
I do not know how to implement it. 
Please help me. please.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ReplyCreate()
    {
        ReplyArticles replyarticles= new ReplyArticles();
        return View(replyarticles);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReplyCreate(ReplyArticles replyArticles)
    {
        try
        {
            replyArticles.ReplyCategory = db.Articles.Where(m => m.ArticleIDX == replyArticles.ReplyArticleIDX).Select(m => m.Category).ToString();
            replyArticles.ReplyDepth = 1;
            replyArticles.ReplyIndent = 2;
            replyArticles.ReplyDate = DateTime.Now;
            replyArticles.ReplyMemberID = User.Identity.Name;

            db.ReplyArticles.Add(replyArticles);
            db.SaveChanges();

            ViewBag.Result = "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Result = "FAIL";
        }
        return View(replyArticles);
    }

ReplyCreate View:
<div class="head_title text-center">
                    <h2>답글 작성</h2>
                    <div class="separator_auto"></div>
                </div>

                <form id="formdata" action="@Url.Action("ReplyCreate", "Board")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <p>
                                <label>제목</label>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReplyTitle, new { placeholder = "제목을 입력하세요." })
                                <a style="margin-left:52.5%"></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12" id="">
                            <label style="margin-right:78%;">분류</label>
                            <p>
                                @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.ReplyCategory)
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-right: 100px;">
                            <br />
                            <p><label style="margin-right:550px;">내용</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <p>
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ReplyContents, new { placeholder = "내용을 입력하세요.", @rows = "10", @cols = "80" })
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dividewhite2"></div>
                        <p>
                            <br />
                            <a style="margin-right:65px;"></a>
                            <button type="submit" onclick="return fnSaveReply();" class="btn btn-sm btn-lgr-str">등록하기</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-lgr-str" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1);">목록이동</button>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

Model : 
public partial class ReplyArticles
{
    [Key]
    public int ReplyIDX { get; set; }

    public int? ReplyArticleIDX { get; set; }

    public int? ReplyFamily { get; set; }

    public int? ReplyDepth { get; set; }

    public int? ReplyIndent { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string ReplyTitle { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string ReplyContents { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ReplyCategory { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string ReplyMemberID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ReplyDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/866143/Learn-MVC-Project-in-days-Day

Comment: we are not here to do you (home)work, please show us the specific error that you are getting and where it happens, then we can help you for you sure

Comment: I want to know the relevant material or the site with that source. When I looked up github, the related source did not come out. I want to improve my skills while watching the source. I am currently studying asp.net mvc.

Comment: and what do you mean by "answer the board" ?

Comment: Hierarchical structure means board. Answer type means bulletin board.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypEbm.jpg

Comment: This is a bulletin board with the above structure.

Comment: You probably need a loop and/or recursive function which will gradually generate some hierarchical HTML based on your data structure. Beyond that it's difficult to give more help without doing the whole solution for you, which is beyond the scope of this site. If you have no idea how to approach a problem, do some more research and study. For a beginner this is a reasonably complex task actually. Build up your skills gradually. If you want to look into this further I have given you some hints on what to study.

Comment: Let's learn about recursive functions. thank you!!!!

Comment: When creating an answer board using the mvc pattern, should I build it using a query statement? Should I use query statements?